# Our team is seeing an error while trying to deploy to production with Heroku CLI

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

We've been trying to troubleshoot this for a while but aren't finding a solution that works, so we'd like to share part of the console output here:

```
remote:    > husky install
remote:     
remote: sh: 1: husky: not found
remote: npm ERR! code 127
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/build_157848d1
remote: npm ERR! command failed
remote: npm ERR! command sh -c husky install
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!   /tmp/npmcache.seRIW/_logs/2021-09-25T00_40_22_168Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote: npm ERR! file sh
remote: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! test@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild: `npm i -f`
remote: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
```

Any additional insights are appreciated.

Comment: You tried to install husky and it could not be found. Have you declared or located the husky package where it can be properly installed or found by Heroku?

Comment: We tried to install husky via npm; is there another step that we should include?

Comment: Try installing it with yarn...

Comment: can you show the package.json, the command you used to install husky, and the script you run to deploy? It's just failing because husky isn't installed.

Comment: No, don't use `npm` _or_ `yarn` interactively. You must simply add it as a dependency and let _Heroku_ install it for you.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was the combination of the following:

1. `husky` was under the `devDependencies` key in my `package.json`.
2. The server had the following environment param: `NODE_ENV=production`, which causes `npm install` to install everything only under the `dependencies`, ignoring `devDependencies`, and so `husky` was not installed.
3. Under the `scripts` key in `package.json`, I had the following key-value pair: `"prepare": "husky install"`. The `prepare` script is being automatically run after a successful `npm install`. The problem you've described happens because `husky` was not installed, and so the `prepare` script fails.

Solutions:

1. Install `devDependencies` as well. One way to do it is: `npm install --include dev`.
2. Move `husky` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`.